# Isolated singularities nature

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the nature of the isolated singularities $a=0$ of the following function.
Can anybody check if it's right what I'm doing?

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-ze^{z}}$. If we look at the denominator $n(z)=z-z e^z$ we see that $z=0$ is a zero of order 2 (simply taking derivates and substituting).
From this we can write $n(z)=z^2h(z)$ with $h(0)\neq 0$. So $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2h(z)}$.  Now we take the limit $\lim_{z->0} f(z)z^2=\lim_{z->0} \frac{z}{1-e^z}=\lim_{z->0} \frac{1}{-e^z}=-1\neq0$ so $z=0$ is a pole of order 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. Since
$$z-ze^z = z(1-e^z)=z(1-1-z-z^2/2-\dots) = -z^2-z^3/2-\dots$$
the denominator has a zero of order $2$ at $z=0$. The numerator is constant, so the quotient has a pole of order $2$.